# react native navigation.goback is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile

For Context, I am trying to learn React Native to build a small mobile application. I read over the docs at [reactnavigation.org](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/) and got my basic structure set up, and then went on to follow [this guide](https://fritz.ai/getting-started-with-react-native-and-expo-using-hooks) in order to add some functionality to the app.

At this point all I'm trying to do is have the ability to add elements to a list and have that list update. I am going to have the list data be populated via an API later on, but right now I just need to get it working with local user data before trying to add in API calls.

Most of the guide worked relatively well, however when I got to section 11, "using navigation parameters to update the state". The code to add to the list seems to work without issue, however, when I try to add in the `navigation.goback()` code, I run into issues.

First, I get the following warning:

```js
WARN  Non-serializable values were found in the navigation state. Check:

Add Drink > params.addDrink (Function)
```

If I dismiss the warning and try to click the save icon, I get the following error:

```js
 ERROR  TypeError: navigation.goBack is not a function (it is undefined), js engine: hermes
```

The button component I am using is as follows:

```js
<FAB
    style={styles.fab}
    small
    icon='plus'
    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Add Drink', {
    addDrink
    })}
/>
```

The state and 'add drink' function look like this:

```js
  const [drinks, setDrinks] = React.useState([])

  const addDrink = drink => {
    drink.id = drinks.length + 1
    setDrinks([...drinks, drink])
  }
```

and the "add drink" screen, the state and save function look as follows:

```js
function AddDrinkScreen(navigation) {

  const [drinkTitle, setDrinkTitle] = React.useState('')
  const [drinkValue, setDrinkValue] = React.useState('')

  function onSaveDrink() {
    navigation.route.params.addDrink({ drinkTitle, drinkValue })
    navigation.goBack()
  }
...
...
```

I have tried to keep it succinct, however, I have also made a pastebin that has the full code from each of the screens.

[The main screen to display the list](https://pastebin.com/yPjz0z2b)

[The add drink screen](https://pastebin.com/90emTyQA)

If anyone could help me figure out why I can't call the navigate.goback() function after updating my list, that would be super helpful.

If anyone alternatively has any suggestions on a good place to learn modern ReactNative development, that would be grand as well - I come from a Python and Golang background, but for some reason react and especially react native are proving extremely difficult for me and I keep running into issues that take me days (or worse) to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one of the issue is the `addDrink` function is accepting one parameter and when calling the funtion youre passing two arguments.
you need to fix that.

```
navigation.route.params.addDrink({ drinkValue })
```

Try it like that

```
function AddDrinkScreen(props) {
   const {route, navigation} = props
   const { addDrink } = route?.params || {}; // Use optional chaining
   const [drinkTitle, setDrinkTitle] = React.useState('')

  function onSaveDrink() {
      addDrink({ drinkTitle, drinkValue })
      navigation.goBack()
     }
```

Comment: That did it! 

Thank you sooo much!
I've been beating my head against the wall for a few days on this, I was actually in the process of implementing Redux, which I knew I was going to need eventually but thought was extreme overkill for this particular instance.

Good to know I just wasn't passing/handling the props properly!

Comment: Great to hear that it worked for you! That's what the Stack Overflow community is all about. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

in the AddDrinkScreen Change them passed parameter from `(navigation)` to `({navigation})`. This should fix the issue

```
function AddDrinkScreen({ route, navigation }) {
...
}
```

Comment: I made the suggested change and am now getting the following error instead:
 ```ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined, js engine: hermes```

the line it's referencing is the following:
```function onSaveDrink() {
    navigation.route.params.addDrink({ drinkTitle, drinkValue })```

Comment: Have you added both `({route, navigation})` to the parameters ?

Comment: I did try to add both route and navigation to the values of the function, but it still gave me the same error I listed above. 

I changed the code to pass 'props' as the value instead as specified in the other answer and that did the trick.

Thank you so much for your answers though, I appreciate you trying!